# Python List generating a problem as if it was a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to build a simple search engine using Bert. In the code bellow I am just trying to set my arrays to build the model.

```
S, X, Y = [], [], []
 
for category in categories:
  print(category)
  sents = reuters.sents(categories=category)
  sents = [' '.join(sent) for sent in sents][:max_samples]
  print(type(X))
  X.append(bert_vectorizer(sents, verbose=True))
  Y += [category] * len(sents)
  S += sents
  X = np.vstack(X)
```

Howerver I am getting the following error even when I am creating a simple python list (type(X) is <class 'list'>. The code output is:

```
 wheat
<class 'list'>
From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py:1475: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
256/256 [==============================] - 250s 975ms/step
tea
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-857a4bef6397> in <module>()
     11   sents = [' '.join(sent) for sent in sents][:max_samples]
     12   print(type(X))
---> 13   X.append(bert_vectorizer(sents, verbose=True))
     14   #np.append(X, bert_vectorizer(sents, verbose=True))
     15   Y += [category] * len(sents)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

As you can see, X is a list. What could be a solution to this? Thanks for the atention and help!

Comment: "type(X) is <class 'list'>" It *clearly is not*, at least *at the point where the error is reported* - because the only code shown that says `append` is `X.append(bert_vectorizer(sents, verbose=True))` - and the error message says that it was looking for an `append` method but couldn't find it, because the thing it's looking at - i.e., `X` - is a `numpy.ndarray` (i.e., not a list).

Comment: Hint: where the code says `X = np.vstack(X)`, what do you expect will be the type of `X` after that line of code? (What does the documentation for `np.vstack` say it will be?) Now: consider that this code is *in a loop*. Therefore, what will happen at the `X.append(bert_vectorizer(sents, verbose=True))` line, the *next* time through the loop?

Comment: Hint: according to your intended process for the code, how many times *should* `X = np.vstack(X)` happen? According to how the code is indented, how many times *does* it happen?

Comment: The error was not fabricated. I guess the problem is in np.vstack. It returns a numpy array. Karl Knechtel maybe got it right.

Comment: What they mean by "fabricated" is that you are typing out what you believe to be the relevant portion of the error message. Please do not do that. Instead, for Stack Overflow questions you should [show a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146), copied and pasted (not retyped - but you can censor any sensitive data such as a username in a file path), and formatted like code. For Python, this means copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end.

Comment: Ah, I see you already edited to do just that - plus the debug output, even better. As you can now see: the `print type(X)` statement produces `<class 'list'>` the first time, but `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` the second time. It is just as I supposed.

Comment: Thanks. I worked now. I will stop fabricating reponses from now then.